# Dynamically change kendo row height so it fills the parent container grid

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid

I have a kendo-grid set in my HTML:

```
<div class="filesOverview">
  <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
    [scrollable]="'virtual'"
    [selectable]="true"
    [pageable]="true"
    [pageSize]="10"
    [resizable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
    <kendo-grid-column field="FileName" title="FileName"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="FileType" title="FileType"></kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>

  <kendo-button class="downloadButton">Download</kendo-button>
</div>
```

And my .scss file:

```
.k-grid {
  height: 95%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filesOverview {
  border: 2px solid $gray;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

With this, I have my filesOverview but the row height is too small to fill the container:

[image: Example]

What am I missing to make it so the row height is adjusted dynamically to fill out the grid height?